# How do I get the address of the address of a variable (&& is a compiler-error)?

Tags: c, pointers, cuda

I have a quick question that I can't seem to find online.

I am using CUDA to do some GPU work, and I need some data allocated on the GPU. The cudaMalloc function goes like this:

```
cudaMalloc(void** identifier, size_t space);
```

Easy enough. So, let's allocate an integer.

```
int i = 5;
cudaMalloc((void**)&(&i), sizeof(int));
```

But this errors ("expression must be an lvalue or a function designator"). The apparent workaround is to declare `i` as a pointer to begin with, and then take the address of it, and that works perfectly fine; I just hate workarounds.

I feel like this question should have an obvious answer - after all, the `**`, `***` and even `**********` work just fine in C. So, how do I get the address of the address of a variable 'cleanly'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's *not* a workaround; that's the right way to do it.

The function wants the address of a pointer to `int`, because it's going to set that pointer to point to an `int` that it has just allocated. Therefore you need the address of a real, allocated pointer. An expression like "&&i" asks the compiler to give you the address of i -- which is a pure number, with no storage location -- and then give you a pointer to that value, which of course it can't do.

So you want to say

```
int *p;
cudaMalloc((void**)&p, sizeof(int));
```

Now `*p` is the `int` that was allocated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does make sense now why I can't do it.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You cannot cast `int **` to `void **`. Instead the variable `p` must have type `void *` so that `&p` has type `void **`. You can then convert `p` (not `&p`) to `int *` either implicitly or via a cast.

Comment: @R..: Well, you *can* cast `int**` to `void**`, and it's even likely to "work", but it's probably undefined behavior.

Comment: It's definitely UB just due to aliasing violations, but it's also possible that `int *` and `void *` have different representations.

Comment: @R: not only is the answer not incorrect, the entire CUDA runtime API is predicated on that precisely that sort of cast. The result `*p` holds is, infact, an *address in another memory space* (the GPU) and there are all sorts of internal things done inside CUDA to guarantee that the representation of `int *` on the host CPU and `void *` on the GPU are always the same.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the address of an address isn't possible.  Only *objects* have addresses, and an address is not an object.  You can assign an address to a pointer (which is an object) and then take the address of that pointer, which is what you describe as your 'workaround'.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a reference to a reference because `&i` is not stored anywhere, you can't access its memory location since it doesn't exist.

You should use a pointer to an int.

```
int *i = calloc(sizeof(int),1);
```

then its reference will be an address of a pointer variable which is stored somewhere. Of course you can't do it in a local scope if pointer needs to be valid also outside scope because you would allocate on the stack.